# How can I add a custom column to the "Manage Categories" table?

Tags: plugin-development

I've done this with posts, but I can't find the proper way to reference the category table's columns.

I'm trying to add a column titled "Image" to the table, so that when the table grid of categories is displayed, if there is a category image assigned to the category, it will appear in the grid.

The first step for me is to determine the proper filter to address in order to insert the columb into the table.

I've tried each of these to no avail...

```
add_filter('manage_categories_columns', 'myFunction', 10, 2);
add_filter('manage_category_columns', 'myFunction', 10, 2);

function myFunction($cat_columns)
{
    $cat_columns['cat_image_thumb'] = 'Image';
    return $cat_columns;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The filter is [`manage_{$screen->id}_columns`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L761), and `$screen->id` is `edit-category`, giving you `manage_edit-category_columns`.

I found this by placing a `var_dump()` in `get_column_headers()`, which is called by `print_column_headers()`, which is called in `wp-admin/edit-tags.php`, the page where you edit the category items.

Comment: @Jan: Thanks! That did it for the column header. Now I'm trying to use your trace route to find out how to add the row insert. Looking into edit-tags.php I see the "tag_rows" call, which I believe is what creates the rows, but I can't locate that function in order to var_dump to get the filter name. Any ideas?

Comment: @Scott: If you're talking about a hierarchical taxonomy like categories, `tag_rows()` calls `_term_rows()`, which calls `_tag_row()`. [This function calls the `manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column` action](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.4/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L481), which would be `manage_category_custom_column` for you.

Comment: @Jan thanks. I'm able to set the action, but can't seem to get the echo to respond.. action > add_action('manage_category_custom_column', 'myFunction', 10, 2);

Comment: @Scott: Indeed, I was wrong, it is a *filter*, not an action, so you should return the content you want to display, not echo it - in contrast to post custom columns, where you have to echo it.

Comment: OK, that's better. Works perfectly with filter and return vs action and echo. Thanks Jan!

Comment: @Jan, It doesn't appear that the category id is being passed to the function. I've got two arguments in the function call, the first one is empty and the 2nd one contains the id of the custom row. Should I take that to a dedicated question since we've pretty much answered the original one?

Comment: @Scott: Probably best to ask it as a new question indeed.

Comment: Just found it. Its the 3rd argument. I had to change the filter to 10,3 and the function becomes myColumnRows($empty_arg, $column_name, $category_id)

Comment: @Jan, is this common that the first argument is empty?

Comment: @Scott: Here it is normal: if no plugin gives anything to display in the column, it should be empty. Remember, this is a filter: the first argument is the value that your callback will be changing. `echo '<td>'; do_action( 'custom_column' ); echo '</td>';` converted to a filter becomes `echo '<td>'; echo apply_filters( 'custom_column', '' ); echo '</td>';`.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the column name

```
function manage_my_category_columns($columns)
{
 // add 'My Column'
 $columns['my_column'] = 'My Column';

 return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-category_columns','manage_my_category_columns');
```

Next we want to put the data in it:

```
function manage_category_custom_fields($deprecated,$column_name,$term_id)
{
 if ($column_name == 'my_column') {
   echo 'test';
 }
}
add_filter ('manage_category_custom_column', 'manage_category_custom_fields', 10,3);
```

I hope this was useful.

Comment: Yes, it was helpfull. Thank you @LeoDang

Answer (score 6):

In addition to @LeoDang's example, the custom_column is applied to custom taxonomy based on the following filters.

Tested and validated in Wordpress 3.8

1.**Adding Custom Column header**

```
// these filters will only affect custom column, the default column will not be affected
// filter: manage_edit-{$taxonomy}_columns
function custom_column_header( $columns ){
    $columns['header_name'] = 'Header Name for Display'; 

    return $columns;
}
add_filter( "manage_edit-shop-subcategory_columns", 'custom_column_header', 10);
```

2.**Adding Custom Column Data to corresponding Column Header**

```
// parm order: value_to_display, $column_name, $tag->term_id
// filter: manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column
function custom_column_content( $value, $column_name, $tax_id ){
    // var_dump( $column_name );
    // var_dump( $value );
    // var_dump( $tax_id );

    // for multiple custom column, you may consider using the column name to distinguish

    // although If clause is working, Switch is a more generic and well structured approach for multiple columns
    // if ($column_name === 'header_name') {
        // echo '1234';
    // }
    switch( $column_name ) {
          case 'header_name1':
               // your code here
               $value = 'header name 1';
          break;

          case 'header_name2':
               // your code here
               $value = 'header name 2';
          break;

          // ... similarly for more columns
          default:
          break;
    } 

    return $value; // this is the display value
}
add_action( "manage_shop-subcategory_custom_column", 'custom_column_content', 10, 3);
```

You may also refer to the [gist code shared online](https://gist.github.com/simongcc/8395576) for any update and additional notes.

Comment: Everything is commented out in step 2.

Comment: @tehlivi Thanks for the comment. Although it was aged ago, I updated it with more explanations and hopefully could help future audiences.