# Filter to shorten column content on edit-tags.php

Tags: filters, columns

I am trying to get the content of columns in the edit-tags.php page. I have been trying to do it, first I tried to get the columns.

```
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'get_columns'); 
function get_columns( $cols ) {
    error.log($cols);
}
```

But it did nothing. I tried the same thing with everithing I could think of to no avail.

And then I tried this code I found around

```
  $wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Terms_List_Table');
  error.log($wp_list_table);
```

Which also did nothing. 
How can this be done? I can't even select the columns

Comment: you mean to shorten taxonomy description that's displayed in the table list?

Comment: check out this one http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/how-can-i-add-a-custom-column-to-the-manage-categories-table

Comment: Yes, what I'm being asked to do mainly consist in shorten the description(everithing that exceeds x number of characters, really). Now, while I could obtain the header of the columns(thank you for that), I still don't know how the shortening can be done

Comment: I think I want something like this, but I cannot implement it: add_filter( 'excerpt_edit_pre', 'modify_field_size', 10, 2 );